NavigationStack in a custom presented view is connected to NavigationStack of the presenting view
I need to present a view with custom presentation style. I have implemented CustomPresentationView that presents UIHostingController using a plain UIViewController:
struct CustomPresentationView<ViewContent: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        @Binding private var isPresented: Bool
        
        init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
            self._isPresented = isPresented
            super.init()
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            isPresented = false
        }
    }
    
    @Binding private var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder private let content: () -> ViewContent
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> ViewContent) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.content = content
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        UIViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        if isPresented {
            if uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
                let view = content()
                    .environment(\.close, CloseAction(isPresented: $isPresented))
                let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
                hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
                uiViewController.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
            }
        } else if
            let presentedViewController = uiViewController.presentedViewController,
            !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed
        {
            presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(isPresented: $isPresented)
    }
}

and a modifier looks like this:
struct CustomPresentationModifier<ViewContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding private var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder private let viewContent: () -> ViewContent
    
    public init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder viewContent: @escaping () -> ViewContent) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.viewContent = viewContent
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(CustomPresentationView(isPresented: _isPresented, content: viewContent))
    }
}

public extension View {
    func customPresentation<ViewContent: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder viewContent: @escaping () -> ViewContent) -> some View {
        modifier(CustomPresentationModifier(isPresented: isPresented, viewContent: viewContent))
    }
}

Everything seems to work fine except one thing: it works weird if content is wrapped in NavigationStack. However it works fine with native .sheet() modifier.
Pay attention at the red button in the top right corner. With custom presentation it appears on the parent view.
If i remove the top level NavigationStack or move .customPresentation() out of it, it is got fixed. But this is not an option for me due to navigation architecture.
Here is the full project https://github.com/claustrofob/PresentedNavigationStack
How can i fix it?

=========== UPDATE ===========
The thing looks even more weird if i try to push in presented view.
With custom presenter it pushes to the parent navigation stack.

=========== UPDATE 2 with solution ===========
@Immanuel solution works but not exactly the way i wanted it to have. But it gave me a confidence that it is possible to get an easy fix on that.
And the solution is simple, i just need to wrap the UIHostingController creation in DispatchQueue.main.async. It is somehow breaks that weird connection between 2 navigation stacks.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
    uiViewController.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
}


Hi @claustrofob, do you need only custom presentation or you also need to push view from custom presentation?

@Immanuel NavigationStack does not work in a custom presented view if there is another NavigationStack around parent view.

Issues - 1) custom presentation appears on the parent view, 2) pushes view to the parent navigation stack.
The both issues are happening when trying to present the controller in updateUIViewController function.
The solution was to move the button inside the view controller and present the controller on button action. And remove the present logic from updateUIViewController function. Because of this you have to manually set the size for 'CustomPresentationView' and 'UIButton'.
struct CustomPresentationView<ViewContent: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    private let content: () -> ViewContent
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> ViewContent) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.content = content
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(controller: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        let controller = CustomUIViewController(isPresented: $isPresented, content: content)
        controller.coordinator = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        
        let controller: CustomPresentationView<ViewContent>
        
        init(controller: CustomPresentationView<ViewContent>) {
            self.controller = controller
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            controller.isPresented = false
        }
        
    }
    
    class CustomUIViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        private let content: () -> ViewContent
        weak var coordinator: Coordinator?
        
        init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> ViewContent) {
            self._isPresented = isPresented
            self.content = content
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            configureButton()
        }
        
        func configureButton() {
            var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.gray()
            configuration.title = "Present custom"
            configuration.cornerStyle = .capsule
            configuration.baseForegroundColor = UIColor.red
            configuration.buttonSize = .large
            
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.configuration = configuration
            view.addSubview(button)
            
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            
            button.addAction(UIAction(
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.onButtonTap()
                }
            ),for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        func onButtonTap() {
            let view = content()
                .environment(\.close, CloseAction(isPresented: $isPresented))
            let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = coordinator
            present(hostingViewController, animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
                self?.isPresented = true
            })
        }
        
    }
    
}

Usage in view
 CustomPresentationView(isPresented: $isPresentedCustom) {
    NavigationStack {
         PresentedView(title: "Presented custom")
     }
 }
 .frame(width: 150, height: 80)


Brilliant! This is not exactly the way i wanted it to have, but it works and it helped me to find a fix for my original solution. I just had to wrap UIHostingController creation in DispatchQueue.main.async. It is somehow breaks that strange connection between 2 navigation stacks.

I think the problem is in your if statement
if isPresented {
        if uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
            let view = content()
                .environment(\.close, CloseAction(isPresented: $isPresented))
            let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            uiViewController.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
        }
    } else if
        let presentedViewController = uiViewController.presentedViewController,
        !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed
    {
        presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

You have to remember that UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController so when you call presentedViewController on it you are calling the root view controller here. If the rootView is being dismissed you don't need to dismiss it. I think what you're trying to get is always going to be the presented view controller here.
I think you mean something like this, but I can't test right now.
if isPresented {
    if uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
        let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
        uiViewController.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
    } else if let stack =  uiViewController.presentedViewController.isMember(of: UINavigationController.self) {
        if stack.rootViewController == nil {
            let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
            hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
            stack.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
} else
    uiViewController.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
}

Update
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    if isPresented,
       uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
        let view = content()
            .environment(\.close, CloseAction(isPresented: $isPresented))
        
        let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        hostingViewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        if let controller = uiViewController.navigationController {
            controller.pushViewController(hostingViewController, animated: true)
        } else {
            uiViewController.present(hostingViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

This is not a working solution, but may get you closer to solving the issue. It has a bug somewhere that causes the whole stack to double layer and then dismiss the entire navigation view. You may have to build a new nav stack in code. I believe it has something to do with the dismiss action, but I've run out of time. If you can't figure it out I'll try to dive into it more later.

Unfortunately it does not make much sense. uiViewController.presentedViewController is an instance of UIHostingController and not UINavigationController

I'll take a look at it in detail today and try writing some code to see for sure what's going on.

It's definitely a stack issue. If I remove the NavigationStack from around mainView() in ContentView() it works fine.

Yes, it is. It also works fine with an obsolete NavigationView, however it is not an option for me. Would be nice to find a workaround for NavigationStack.

If you figure it out please post your answer. Otherwise I'll work on it some more later when time allows

It seems like this is going to be a bug in NavigationStack I went back and tried my code on NavigationView and you're right it works fine, but not on the newer NavStack. The old NavigationView show two back buttons though which obviously will not work for shipping applications. Is there a specific need to go into UIKit or are you just experimenting?

That is quite a common scenario to have a custom presentation transition for a view controller wrapped in a navigation controller. I am now working on a custom NavigationStack view, that supports custom presentations.
